# "Ink" as a term for coffee?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, expressions, idioms, terminology

I've stumbled upon a thesaurus entry for the word "ink" that connects it to various words to describe coffee or caffeine, none of which I have -ever- heard in my life! I'm a coffee-drinker, I'm American, I live in New York, and I've heard a lot of people talk about coffee and never once use the word ink to describe it... Scanning the first page of Google results provides no information on this.

My assumption, given that other online thesauruses have no mention of this coffee connection, is that this is just a mistake on [Thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/ink), but I'm hoping it's either something antiquated and archaic, or some kind of inside joke put in Roget's 21st Century Thesaurus (the cited source according to Thesaurus.com)

Any insights?

[image: Thesaurus.com result for "ink"...]

Comment: "Other thesauruses don't mention it" – [WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/ink.html) does.

Comment: Also, see: https://thesaurus.plus/related/coffee/ink | the second entry on the right column: "Coffee and ink are semantically related. Sometimes you can replace term "Coffee" with "Ink", this [sic] nouns are similar." | note the typo; the rest of the page is also a bit iffy. It's possible that thesaurus.com's algorithm found it mistakenly.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about complete garbage showing on a defective thesaurus web page. The line underneath the 'head' word **INK** initially says "**as in coffee**". Shift it along to any of the other "as in" categories (**infamousness, mark, notoriety, notoriousness, publicity,...**) to see even more ridiculous "synonyms". That website would appear to be totally worthless.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It's true that the entry is really awful, but the website is Thesaurus.com, which is (I think) the most reputable online thesaurus.

Comment: @Heartspring: How is it "reputable" to be told that synonyms for **ink** include ***attention
clout
commercial
distribution
fame
hoopla
hype
noise
notoriety
propaganda
PR
advertising
announcement
ballyhoo
billing
blurb
boost
broadcasting
currency
handout
limelight
pitch
plug
press
promulgation
puff
puffery
pushing
release
report
scratch
spotlight
spread*** ...??!! If there is any "truth" there, it's drowned out by all the garbage. Worthless website, imho.

Comment: I also seriously question two of the "**as in**" categories on that web page. It's in wiktionary (barely a step up from Urban Dictionary), but [***infamousness*** isn't really a word.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=infamousness%2Cinfamy&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) And ***notoriousness*** is no better. (My spell checker doesn't like either! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers this Dictionary.com LLC ***isn't*** Roget's 21st Century Thesaurus as claimed. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roget%27s_Thesaurus) states: *The name "Roget" is trademarked in parts of the world, such as the United Kingdom. By itself, it is not protected in the United States, where use of the name "Roget" in the title of a thesaurus does not necessarily indicate any relationship to Roget directly; it has come to be seen as a **generic thesaurus name**.*

Comment: @WeatherVane: Well, *thank you* for that! I didn't really want to be put in the position of claiming that Roget's Thesaurus isn't worth the electronic ink it's written in, but "crude AI-generated" lists as per my previous comment (only one of half-a-dozen equally useless "categories") really are garbage. And even if someone *can* find historical references to (pre-Victorian?) coffee being called "ink", ***so what**?* I doubt OP would have bothered to ask the question in the first place if it hadn't been for that stupid "synonyms" list.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, while I share your skepticism about this matter, the best way to settle it is to leave the question open, so that, if any evidence of the word being actually used that way exists, it can be posted. If nobody comes forward with such evidence, that will support your argument that including *ink* as a word for coffee should be disregarded.

Comment: I remember that, in Colombia,  a cup of black coffee would sometimes be called un tinto.  Since tinta is Spanish for ink,  this could have given rise to some regional slang.

Comment: Could always be a trap street. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_street. FWIW, infamousness was more common than *ugly cousin* until fairly recently.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that seems to be the case. [Green’s Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/as6j2ly) gives as the 5th meaning of the noun *ink*:

> strong, bitter coffee.

Then it quotes C. Samolar ‘*Argot of the Vagabond*’ (1927):

> Other names for coffee are ***ink***, *mud, alkali and embalming fluid*.

Although, it was said in the comments, I will just include [WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/ink.html#C0-5)'s entry here, which I had found simultaneously. I find it quite peculiar that Word Hippo does not list it as slang, and gives quite a technical definition to it:

> A beverage made by infusing the beans of the coffee plant in hot water.

[Enjoyjava](https://enjoyjava.com/words-to-describe-coffee/) lists ***ink*** under *nicknames and slang*, or synonyms of coffee. [Easytoespresso](https://easytoespresso.com/coffee-slang/) even explains that

> Not surprisingly, *black coffee nicknames often come from its similarity in appearance to oily or dirty liquids*:
>
> Dirt
> Mud
> Ink
> Oil
> Sludge
> Worm dirt.

Comment: Might be worth giving that to OED, who don't mention coffee at all (but do mention *red ink* as referring to red wine).

Comment: Coffee has even been *used* as ink.

Comment: This does prove that this usage can be found somewhere (and so rules out the OP's suspicion that its being listed in one thesaurus was a mistake), but one can't help wanting to know more: what kind of slang does this usage belong to? In what social circles would it be readily understood? Is it current or obsolete? The OP is probably far from being alone in having never heard it in the wild.

Comment: @jsw29: It was listed in 1927 in some long-forgotten publication *Argot of the Hobo* (the name hardly inspires confidence! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers you made me laugh! Surely "Argot of the Hobo" expresses a certain *je ne sais quoi*?

Comment: @WeatherVane: Suggests a particular variety of Victoria *dilettante* to me. I can't remember the author, but I know I failed for quite long enough to find anything about him when I *was* following up the source (which I've forgotten now! :) Maybe he was a bit behind the times. Anyway, I bet half of what we're told is "hobo slang" is just made up by the lexicographers. It's not like many of those lexicographers have *first-hand* knowledge whereof they write.

Comment: @WeatherVane It's been used as ink, though likely more often accidentally than intentionally!